# Windows Hooks do not trigger events and windows starts lagging. (Using globalmousekeyhook in C#)

Tags: c#, hook, setwindowshookex, .net-4.8, mousekeyhook

I currently work with the [Steelseries GameSense SDK](https://github.com/SteelSeries/gamesense-sdk) to make my own effects etc. for my keyboard and mouse.

To light up my mouse and keyboard on clicks and presses, I use the [globalmousekeyhook](https://github.com/gmamaladze/globalmousekeyhook) library.

Unfortunately, the mouse and keyboard events don't get triggered.

Also, my mouse starts lagging, and keyboard input gets delayed.

The lag and the delay only stay for about half a minute.

I suspect that windows removes the hooks because it detects the lag.

I also tried [this example program](https://github.com/gmamaladze/globalmousekeyhook/tree/vNext/examples/ConsoleHook) and everything works fine there.

Here is the code:

```cs
private static readonly IKeyboardMouseEvents GlobalHook = Hook.GlobalEvents();
```

```cs
static InputManager()
{
    Logger.Log("Starting...", Logger.Type.Info);
    GlobalHook.KeyDown += KeyEvent;
    GlobalHook.MouseDownExt += MouseEvent;
    Logger.Log("Ready!", Logger.Type.Info);
}
```

And the event functions:

```cs
private static void KeyEvent(object sender, KeyEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    Logger.Log(eventArgs.KeyCode.ToString());
}
```

```cs
private static void MouseEvent(object sender, MouseEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    Logger.Log(eventArgs.Button.ToString());
}
```

You can find the whole class (and the project) [here](https://github.com/habetuz/KaLE/blob/master/KaLE.InputManager.cs).

The constructor is the only thing that gets executed in the program.

What I found regarding the lag is that the event function has to be fast. That cannot be the problem in my case because the `Logger.Log()` function is fast, and the lag also occurs when using `Console.WriteLine()`.

As I said, the example program runs fine. I tried copying the example code, but that made no difference. The only real difference between my program and the example program is that the example uses .Net Core but I use .Net Framework (4.8). Could that be the reason? If it is the reason, is there any way to use the library with .Net Framework?
I look forward to any help.

Comment: It's normal to if you try to respond all events. You may try logging in a new thread but it will also use unnecessary system resources. 
            **private static void KeyEvent(object sender, KeyEventArgs eventArgs)
            { Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Logger.Log(eventArgs.KeyCode.ToString()); 
            });
            }**

Comment: @OlivierRogier It even lags when I comment out Logger.Log() and therefore empty the event function. 
Also unfortunately the linked wrapper does not suit my case because I need to hook all events.

Comment: @aliassce I tried your suggestion and it still lags.
The [example](https://github.com/gmamaladze/globalmousekeyhook/tree/vNext/examples/ConsoleHook) I linked also logs all events, but it does not lag there for some reason.

Comment: `Console.ReadLine` in `Program.Main()` is blocking everything, in any case you are not running a meesage loop, so I'm not sure what you expect to happen. Note that the example code you supply is *very* different, it sets up a message loop with `Application.Run(new ApplicationContext());` I must say I don't understand why `InputManager.Start` is empty and all the hookup code is in the static constructor. That doesn't sound very safe.

Comment: @Charlieface I do not have a message loop right now cause I first need to get the mouse and keyboard hook working. I expect a console output with the key or the mouse button I click (you can see that in the `KeyEvent` and `MouseEvent` functions).
The static constructor gets called before any other method gets called. So when you call `InputManager.Start()` it runs the constructor. This has the advantage that the "start" function gets called even when you call any method of the class. 
Could you explain why `Console.ReadLine()` is blocking? Is there an alternative to keep the program running?

Comment: `Console.ReadLine` waits for an input on `stdin` pipe, and will block the pump on the message queue. You *need* a message pump because the hook receives messages via the message queue. Is there another method: of course, just run the message loop and `Console.ReadLine` on different threads

Comment: @Charlieface I made a function `KeepAlive` which only calls `Console.ReadLine()`. As you suggested I run this function on a different thread with `new Thread(KeepAlive).Start()`. This indeed keeps the program running, nevertheless it still lags and no events are triggered. Also there is another side effect: I cannot type into the console anymore (even after Windows removes the hooks). Typing still works on other programs. The changes are [pushed](https://github.com/habetuz/KaLE/blob/master/KaLE.Program.cs).

Comment: I'm completely confused as to why you thought that would work in the way the other code did or why you did not do the same as it. You *need* a message pump. A `while(true) ;` loop is just wasting CPU

Comment: @Charlieface I'm sorry to confuse you. I first tried `Console.ReadLine()` in the `KeepAlive` function but that did not work so I tried with `while(true) ;` loop. I changed it back to `Console.ReadLine()` now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues:

- You need a message pump in order to receive hook messages. For this you can use the following code, as shown in the example you link

```cs
Application.Run(new ApplicationContext());
```

- You now have two things you are trying to do on the same thread: pump the messages and wait for input. Instead, split them into different threads:

```cs
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Logger.Log("Program started. Welcome.", Logger.Type.Info);
    ////GameSense.Controller.Start();
    new Thread(() => Console.ReadLine()).Start();
            
    InputManager.Start();
    
    Application.Run(new ApplicationContext());
    InputManager.End();
    Application.Exit();  // needed to close down the message pump and end the other thread
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm not very familiar with std pumps. Leaned something new today!

Comment: Just checked: I have to call `Application.Run(new ApplicationContext())` in the same thread after `InputManager.Start()`. It only works this way. (The example also has it that way)

Comment: You could do it that way round if you want, then place `Console.ReadLine` in the other thread. I don't think it makes a difference

Comment: It actually only works if you put both on the same thread. `Application.Run(new ApplicationContext())` to start the new std pipe (when I understand it right?) and Console.ReadLine() does not block the "old" pipe? The way it is currently on GitHub works. When I try your code it still lags.

Comment: `Application.Run` doesn't have anything to do with the pipe, and it will block you from using `ReadLine`

Comment: Okay, as I said, I am not very familiar with this stuff. Nevertheless the current state of the answer does not work. The version on my GitHub works.